# User Component Visual Studio Form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio, user-interface

I am used to using Qt and I would like to learn and see what Visual Studio and its Windows Form can do.

What I liked with Qt Creator and its QML interface is to be able to make graphic components that I can reuse and duplicate in a window.
Simple example: a component with an item with several text fields inside. Each time I repeat this component, I access the text field via the name of my parent component.

I can't find this in Visual Studio for the moment. What is the process to create a graphic component with the same design method as a Windows Form (window design)?

Do we have to create a new project each time to create a "user component" library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to use a "UserControl".

you can duplicate, and reuse it however you want.

To add one to your Project: `right-click the project >> Add >> UserControl`.